# Adding conditional items on scope causes isolate scope bindings to break in template but not console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Say I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('foo', []);
angular.module('foo').constant('demoConst', ['foo', 'bar','bazz']);
angular.module('foo').directive('demoDirTwo', ['$injector', function(injector){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div>{{targetList}} WHY IS THIS LOADING?</div>",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      targetConst: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      scope.targetList = injector.get(scope.targetConst);
    }
  }

}])
```

and the following template:

```
  <body ng-app='foo'>
    demo-dir-two target-const='demoConst'></demo-dir-two>
  </body>
```

That will render the contents of the array to the dom in that div

Now say I modify the directive, like so:

```
   scope: {
       targetConst: '@',
       targetList: '@'
   },
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
       if(scope.targetList){
          scope.targetList = JSON.parse(scope.targetList);
       } else if(scope.targetConst){
          scope.targetList = injector.get(scope.targetConst);
       }
    }
```

And do not modify the template. This will no longer display the array. Why? Shouldn't the dom attribute default to undefined? Why doesn't the binding occur later? And why does console debug on scope actually still produce the correct value?

Plunks:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iFJ7YJwiDXPBkUvnCCJp?p=info   (displays array)
http://plnkr.co/edit/QxAgc8CF3kOHdkakK6Ap?p=preview    (does not display array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind `targetList` to an attribute. That creates an observer for that attribute. From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24compile.directive.Attributes)

> The observer function will be invoked once during the next $digest following compilation.

That means it is called **after** your link function is called. And since there is no attribute `targetList`, the property is set to `null`.

If you still want to do it your way then you can do it asynchronously, like

```
$timeout(function() {
    scope.targetList = injector.get(scope.targetConst);
});
```